# Rails database relationships has_many :through but for many to many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I am trying to create my first database in rails that allows me to store data about events.

Assume I have information about the event, the venue(s), and the band(s).

Every event should have at least one venue and band but could possibly have more than one of each.
Each band can be at more than one event.
Each venue can host more than one event.

It seems like "has_many :through" using the "Event" as the ":through" would be the appropriate relationship *IF* there were only one band/venue pair per event.

So what can I do if there can be multiple bands and multiple venues per event?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create tables `events_venues` and `events_bands` and use `has_and_belongs_to_many` to build the relationship. For more details, please read the railscasts tutorial here:

[Many to many](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many)

Comment: Will this allow me to find all venues that a band is playing at and vice versa? Thanks!

Comment: If that's the case, your model relationship should be `event`<--many-to-many-->`venue` and `venue`<--many-to-many-through-event-->`band`

Comment: That would also require event<--many-to-many-->band, correct?

Comment: Yes, you need it as well